# What to do if You get an error in hello world program of C in VS code if you wrote gcc (program name) and ./F1.c to execute

Tags: c, terminal, execute

Error that I am facing :

```
./F1
The term './F1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
 1. CategoryInfo :
: ObjectNotFound: (./F1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
 2. FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Code that I wrote :

```c
1.# include<stdio.h>
2.
3.Int main()
4.{
5.    printf("hello world");
6.    return 0;
7.}
```

Comment: Did you compile it? How did you compile it?

Comment: Your title states you try to execute `./F1.c` which would indicate that you try to run a C source code file instead of the compiled binary. Your question body now contains `./F1`. That does not match. Please provide exact and complete commands you are using. Also does your code really contain line numbers? If yes, that will not work and you must remove them. If not, please don't include them here.

Comment: Also your code cannot compile. There is no type `Int` but only `int`. Please show exactly the code you are compiling and that causes the problems. Also include command to compile your program and messages shown during compilation.

Comment: First I used ./F1.c then ./a.exe

Answer (score 1):

A proper hello world program would be like:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

The things I noticed in your code:

1. There should not be any spaces in-between the hash and the include.
2. There should not be any lines in your actual code.
3. int should not be capitalized.

As far as actually compiling the hello world program. I do not think that gcc would allow you to use a .c or .exe extension for execution.

To compile a single c file

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```

To execute that file

```
./hello
```